# Warning: mail(): Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'

Tags: php, email

I got the above warning when I am trying to send email with ajax from a PHP file. I am trying code:

```
$to = "suman5571@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is subject";

$message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
$message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

$header = "From:suman5571@gmail.com \r\n";
$header = "Cc:dhillon0jags@gmail.com \r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if( $retval == true ) {
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
```

Comment: sorry the whole code is :    $to = "suman5571@gmail.com";
         $subject = "This is subject";
        
         $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
         $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
        
         $header = "From:suman5571@gmail.com \r\n";
         $header = "Cc:dhillon0jags@gmail.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        
         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
        
         if( $retval == true ) {
            echo '1';
         }else {
            echo '0';
         }

Comment: Delete comment. Next time edit the question, not put comment with the edit.

Comment: the `from` part of the header is being overwritten by the `cc`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your sendmail_path settings in php. Also check if the program exists and is installed.

Comment: When i added this code it was working...and email was delivering as well. But next day i checked, it was not working.

Comment: How to do above setting please suggest me.